# Need help finding a subgroup of order $20$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{50}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

My method of looking for an element of the specific order and generating a subgroup by it fails here. I don't see what else to do.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{50}$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $10$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times H$ has order $20$.

Comment: @Levent You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Levent has described is true and here's why: By Lagrange's Theorem, we know that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z_{50}$ such that $[H:\mathbb Z_{50}] = 10$. We know that $\mathbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$. And by definition, $$\mathbb Z_2 \times H= \{(a,b) : a\in\mathbb Z_2, b\in H\},$$ which since $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{50}$ (and $\mathbb Z_2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{50}$ for that matter), it is extremely clear that $\mathbb Z_2\times H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{50}$, and $\mathbb Z_2\times H$ has order $20$ as desired. (This is easily verified through the Cayley table for $\mathbb Z_2\times H$.

Thus, for example, we may choose $H = \{0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45\}$. clearly $|H| = 10$. Then $$\mathbb Z_2\times H = \left\{\begin{matrix}(0,0), & (1,0), & (0,5), & (1,5), & (0,10), \\ (1,10), & (0,15), & (1,15), & (0,20), & (1,20), \\ (0,25), & (1,25), & (0,30), & (1,30), & (0,35), \\ (1,35), & (0,40), & (1,40), & (0,45), & (1,45)\end{matrix}\right\}.$$ This is clearly a subgroup of ${\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{50}}$ since all the left and right components of the ordered pairs are in $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_{50}$ respectively. Hence we've found a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{50}$ with order $20$ as desired.